# Do processes use task_struct or thread_info

Tags: linux, process

I read  threads use `thread_info` , and `task_struct` is a member of `thread_info` , i have a doubt like, processes also use `thread_info` or are they using `task_struct` while allocating memory for process descriptor entry.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by process entry?
If you mean by process creation, then it allocates both thread_info & task_struct(which have all the information related to process like pid, priorities etc) while forking the a process.

Comment: yes it was about process creation, i mean process descriptor entry by entry